# Rewrite URL in web.config

Tags: laravel, iis, web-config

Right now my site is working like that whenever i hit my root site link **mysite.com** i get **mysite.com/public** and sub pages are being accessed as **mysite.com/public/login**.
I want to remove "public" from all URL's.

Here is my web.config (using Laravel's original)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your webserver up so that the /public folder is the site root. If you have to prefix every URL with /public, that means it is currently pointed at the app root.

Answer (score 0):

copy .htaccess from public directory to main directory
change the server.php file to index.php in main directory